# Is there a reason for the parameter missing jQuery/Ajax/phpcUrl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, php-curl

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="application/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title> GeoNames Address</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <label for="vol"> latidue (-90<span>&#176;</span> to 90<span>&#176;</span>)</label>
    <input type="number"  class="lat" id="lat" name="vol" min="-90" max="90">

    <label for="vol2"> longitude (0<span>&#176;</span> to 180<span>&#176;</span>)</label>
    <input type="number"  class="lat" id="lng" name="vol2" min="0" max="180">

    <button id="btnRun" > find address</button>

    <p>houseNumber: <span id="houseNumber"></span><p>
    <p>street: <span id="street"></span><p>
    <p>postalcode: <span id="postalcode"></span><p>
    <p>locality: <span id="locality"></span><p>
    <p>countryCode: <span id="countryCode"></span><p>
      <div id="error"> </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
$('#btnRun').click(function() {
  $.ajax(
    {
      type: 'POST',
      url: "libs/php/address.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        lat: $('#lat').val(),
        lng: $('#lng').val()
      },
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result['data']);

        $('#houseNumber').html(result['data']['houseNumber']);
        $('#street').html(result['data']['street']);
        $('#postalcode').html(result['data']['postalcode']);
        $('#locality').html(result['data']['locality']);
        $('#countryCode').html(result['data']['countryCode']);
      },
       error: function( errorThrown){
        // error code
        console.log("we have reached error ");

        console.log(errorThrown);


       }
    });
});
```

```php
<?php

  $url = 'http://api.geonames.org/addressJSON?lat=' .$_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&username=sherazzi403';

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS)
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
  // api returns data as json
  // print_r($result);
  // decode the json as an associative array so that we can append it to the $output
  $decode = json_decode($result,true);

  // the 'geonames' properrty from the serialized JSON is store into the 'data'
  // element of $output
  $output['data'] = $decode['address'];
  // the correct header information for json is set and $output is converted to jsobn before send it
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  echo json_encode ($output);
?>
```

API: http://api.geonames.org/addressJSON?lat=52.358&lng=4.881&username=sherazzi403

I have tried to keep the code clean so easier to read. Addittionally the HTML page connects to the Js files which reads the output from the PHP using Ajax jQuery post call.

When I run `localhost/address/libs/php/address.php`
on the browser I get missing parameter but I have provided this. I am not sure why it happens and how to resolve it.

Comment: If you run the script like that, you're not passing `lat` and `lng` parameters

Comment: Try `localhost/address/libs/php/address.php?lat=42&lng=71`

Comment: I run it and it return an empty string . the problem is why $_REQUEST['lat']  and $_REQUEST['lng'] doesn't transfer the value from the html form to the php file.

Comment: The AJAX code looks fine to me. Use the Network tab of Dev Tools to see the parameters you're sending and the full response.